# Rails 3 production server complaining that bcrypt-ruby gem is not part of the bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bcrypt-ruby

As can be seen from the following excerpt of the output of a cap deploy `** [out :: 178.79.170.199] Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)` the bcrypt-ruby gem is installed on my server but unicorn is unable to start up properly and is complaining that bcrypt-ruby gem is not part of the bundle.

UPDATE - Exact error message is

```
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:147:in `block in replace_gem': bcrypt-ruby is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
```

I have restarted both my nginx server and unicorn.

How can I fix this?

An excerpt of console output from `cap deploy`

```
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] Using highline (1.6.15)
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] Using net-ssh (2.6.3)
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] Using net-scp (1.0.4)
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] Using net-sftp (2.0.5)
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] Using net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] Using capistrano (2.14.1)
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] Using coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] Using execjs (1.4.0)
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] Using rack-ssl (1.3.3)
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] Using json (1.7.6)
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] 
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] Using rdoc (3.12)
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] 
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] Using thor (0.17.0)
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] Using railties (3.2.11)
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] 
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] Using jquery-rails (2.2.0)
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] 
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] Using kgio (2.8.0)
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] 
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] Using mysql2 (0.3.11)
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] Using bundler (1.2.3)
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] 
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] Using rails (3.2.11)
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] 
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] Using raindrops (0.10.0)
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] 
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] Using rvm-capistrano (1.2.7)
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] 
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] Using sass (3.2.5)
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] Using sass-rails (3.2.6)
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] Using uglifier (1.3.0)
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] Using unicorn (4.5.0)
 ** [out :: 178.79.170.199] Your bundle is complete! It was installed into /home/myuser/myapp/shared/bundle
```

I am having no issues with other gems I have installed.

Comment: Could you post the exact error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by ensuring that th nginx server was re booted properly. I actually had to re-boot the actual OS for this issue to clear itself up as nginx restarts and unicorn restarts just seemed to have no effect.